# x2go unable to locate package x2goserver

Tags: ubuntu, apt, cubian

I'm trying to install x2go on my test server following this: http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:installation:x2goserver (ubuntu)

The repo seems to add fine and gives details on how to use it and what you can install form the repo. But when i run apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsesion i get the following error:

```
E: unable to locate package x2goserver
E: unable to locate package x2goserver-xsession
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please visit the [official X2Go Repository](https://launchpad.net/~x2go/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+index?batch=75) and consider readding/verifying the repository.

Answer (score 1):

After running the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
```

Make sure to do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession -y
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the

```
apt-get update
```

before starting the installation.

If it is'nt the problem, check this [link](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:repositories:debian), it works for me on Debian Jessie.